# Jquery select2 how to invoke custom function while searching

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have this simple select2:

```
<div class="form-group form-material col-4" >
    <select class="form-control" id="mySelect" name="mySelect" data-plugin="select2" data-minimum-input-length="3" required>
    </select>
</div>

<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        let myLoading = $('#myLoading'); // image centered in the screen
        let mySelect = $('#mySelect');
        
        myLoading.hide();
        
        let js_mySelect = {
            init: function () {
                mySelect.select2({
                    ajax: {
                        url: 'myUrl',
                        dataType: 'json'
                    }
                });
            },
        };
        js_mySelect.init();
    }
</script>
```

I'm using `jQuery JavaScript Library v2.2.4`.

I need to display my own spinner while the select2 is retreiving data from the specified url (while it display "Searching..."). And then hide my spinner when it finishes loading data.

I already tried these:

```
mySelect.on('change', function() { alert('test'); myLoading.show(); }); // nothing happens
mySelect.on('keyUp', function() { alert('test'); myLoading.show(); }); // nothing happens
mySelect.on('change', function() { alert('test'); myLoading.show(); }); // nothing happens
$('.select2-search__field').on('keyup', function() { console.log('text'); myLoading.show(); }); // nothing happens

// by doing this it no more works and nothing happens
let js_mySelect = {
    init: function () {
        mySelect.select2({
            ajax: {
                url: 'myUrl',
                dataType: 'json'
            },
            query: function() {
                alert('test');
                myLoading.show();
            }
        });
    },
};

// by doing this it no more works and nothing happens
let js_mySelect = {
    init: function () {
        mySelect.select2({
            ajax: {
                url: 'myUrl',
                dataType: 'json'
            },
            success: function() {
                alert('test');
                myLoading.show();
            }
        });
    },
};
```

All of them run without any error in the browser's console.

Comment: At the end it would have a much greater usability if you fasten up your ajax call so the user must not wait for a select to show possible entries.

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff Are you serious?? Informing the user that the request is in process is essential for a better user experience. Isn't enough to speed up the call, even if it's obvious and already done... Also the elaborations may CORRECTLY needs some times so the user MUST be informed that it's in process instead of displaying nothing, in which case the user may think that something goes wrong or is bad developed.

Comment: Yes I am serious, if the creation of the select list is lasting longer then 1s I would never use this software. Point! If it is not possible to do it that fast a dropdown select is not the right choice...

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff I disagree with you, my call performs complex statistical calculations so it will never end in less than a few seconds. The customer knows this and does not want to spend more to optimize / prepare the data previously. So, can you help me with my question or not?

Comment: Use a function instead of a static value at the url: in the Ajax request. There you can do everything you want before returning the url

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff can you suggest me at least a link that explain that?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a function in the URL parameter of the Ajax request

```
let js_mySelect = {
init: function () {
    mySelect.select2({
        ajax: {
            url: function() { console.log("Test"); return 'myUrl'},
            dataType: 'json'
        }
    });
},
```

};